# Python Global Variable Not Updating as Expected

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm encountering an issue with a Python script where a global variable is not updating as expected. I have a code snippet like the one below:

```
global a
a = None

def load_cached_model():
    print('Loading')
    global a  # Access the global variable
    
    if a is None:
        print('Inside')
        # Load the model if it hasn't been loaded yet
        a = 5
    print('Outside')
    return a
```

load_cached_model()

I expect that on the second run of load_cached_model(), it should not print "Inside" because a should no longer be None after the first run. However, it still prints "Inside" on the second run, which is unexpected.

I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:

- Restarted the Python environment.
- Checked for other code or modifications affecting a.
- Isolated the code in a separate script to ensure it's not influenced by other code.
- Despite these efforts, I'm still seeing "Inside" being printed on the second run.

Can someone please help me understand why the global variable a is not updating as expected and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I can't replicate this: https://www.ideone.com/xqEzsk. No "Inside" on the second run for me.

Comment: Do you mean a second call of the function or do you really mean to run the whole program a second time after it ended?

Comment: ...or do you reimport the module before the second time you call the function?

Comment: @MichaelButscher run the whole again after it has ended.

Comment: @slothrop i meant that i am running the programme again  after it has ran for the first time.

Comment: You have to store and later read the data in/from a file. Global variables don't survive the end of the program.

Comment: I recommend you check out the `pickle` module.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are stored in-memory, just like local variables. That means that when your program terminates, they will be deleted by the garbage collector.

It seems as if you do not want a *global variable*, but instead a *persistent variable* (survives program restarts). This can be achieved by writing the value to disc. The easiest way to do this would be to serialize it in some way, e.g. with `repr()`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

a = None
a_cache = Path("a_cache")

# Retrieve cached value from disk
if a_cache.exists():
    with a_cache.open(mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as a_cache_fp:
        a = eval(a_cache_fp.read())

def load_cached_model():
    print('Loading')
    global a  # Access the global variable
    
    if a is None:
        print('Inside')
        # Load the model if it hasn't been loaded yet
        a = 5
    print('Outside')
    return a

# Update cached value on disk
if a is not None:
    with a_cache.open(mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as a_cache_fp:
        a_cache_fp.write(repr(a))
```

Generally, I would recommend against global variables, by the way. You could also refactor the code to load this value from disk only when you need it.

Sidenote: You do not need to specify `global a` on a module level (first line in your example). This is only necessary if you want to *assign to* the variable *in an enclosed scope*, but has no effect at that location.

Comment: *"This is only necessary before you read the variable in an enclosed scope"* It's actually necessary only if you *reassign* the variable in an enclosed scope. You can read it, or (if its value is mutable) mutate it, without the need for the `global` declaration.

Comment: True, thanks for the correction! Have updated the answer accordingly.